# Change textview of another layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a class "HomeActivity.class" and its layout "activity_home". I need to change the text of a TextView ("TV8") in another layout ("layout_profile"). I tried to use:

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
ConstraintLayout profile=(ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_profile);
TextView TV8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV8);
TV8.setText("MY TEXT IN TV8");`

but my app crush when try to set text at line 4.
Maybe the problem can be the inflated layout: in activty_home layout i have a frame layout that inflate layout_profile where is my textview TV8:

**activity_home**:
[image: activity_home xml ⬇️]

**layout_profile :**
[image: layout_profile xml⬇️]
[Debug application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqLVQ.png)

HOW CAN I CHANGE THE TEXT OF A TEXTVIEW (TV8) IN A LAYOUT(layout_profile) FROM A CLASS(activity_home) THAT HAVE ANOTHER LAYOUT(activty_home)??

Comment: Share your logs from adb logcat as well

Comment: I shared the debug of application.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue in line 3.
Try this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
ConstraintLayout profile=(ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_profile);
TextView TV8 = (TextView) profile.findViewById(R.id.TV8);
TV8.setText("MY TEXT IN TV8");
```

Comment: i have just tried this: ConstraintLayout profile=(ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_profile); but crash.

Comment: No, you try to get you TextView from wrong layout. Look attentively at the line 3 in your code and in my code

Answer (score 0):

You are loading activity_home.xml in the Activity and try to access the view TV8 which is not in activty_home.xml.

R.id.TV8 is part of layout_profile not part of activity_home.xml.

You can access those view which is in layout which is currently loaded in the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Your activity is loading the `activity_main` layout so you can access the views that are present in the layout.

You are trying to access the view present in `layout_profile` which is not loaded and not visible. Until its loaded you can't access the view.
And if the view is not visible there is no point changing the text of that view.
Rather you can store the value in a `flag` and can be used to change the `text` when `layout_profile` is loaded.